# Firebase .getUID NullPointerException when authen

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I will add data to database when I register, but I got

Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

I try something, but don't work

Here's My code

```
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    mRef = database.getReference();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    userID = user.getUid();
btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final String fname = etFname.getText().toString().trim();
            final String lname = etLname.getText().toString().trim();
            final String id_card = etIdCard.getText().toString().trim();
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            final String mobile = etMobile.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fname)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter FirstName!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 8) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 8 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                                UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(fname,lname,id_card,mobile,email);
                                mRef.child("users").child(userID).setValue(userInfo);
                                etFname.setText("");
                                etLname.setText("");
                                etIdCard.setText("");
                                etMobile.setText("");
                                etEmail.setText("");
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register Successfully" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                finish();
                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
    });


}
```

And now get new error like this
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzTt()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.androiddev.army31-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes36.dex)

Now I can fix it because compile on gradle not same version

And got the same thing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the type of auth you have mentioned in the code, Replace it with single line and check if it works

```
        String mUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

You may also check the documentation for full working code example: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

Comment: Thank for reply sorry na how to use your code ? im not sure

Comment: What is the difference between a single liner and what he did? There is not, this is basic java

Comment: Please Refer to the documentation for complete working code in Java -@C.Junior

Answer (score 2):

Check this:

```
if(auth.getCurrentUser() != null){
    uid = auth.getCurrentUser().getUID();
}
```

Comment: thank for reply but it not work

im update my code plz see

Answer (score -1):

```
 FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
 userID = user.getUid();
```

To run above two lines, you must (**I'm stressing you must**) have **username/password** based authenticated in the Firebase. It is throwing `NullPointerException` because most of the novice programmer forget to setup user based authentication in Firebase console.

**You can add the user in Firebase Authentication.**

If you are using **Firebase Realtime Database** then I suggest you add following rules in RULES tab.

```
// These rules grant access to a node matching the authenticated
// user's ID from the Firebase auth token
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Thank reply but i ser

{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Comment: See my updated answer, I am talking about Authentication, you can forget RULES.

Comment: Ok i got it change but have new problem

split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes36.dex)

Comment: Can you show me the line 42 of your RegistryActivity? There is an error. Errors happen in chains. We solve the first error, then second, then third and so on. So, I am assuming this is your first error.